# Vue - watch method using immediate is shown as error by ESlint

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I am using a Vue **Watch** method as follows with **`immediate: true`**

```
watch: {
    currentQuestion() {
      // console.log("Watch currentQuestion", "Start");
      immediate: true;
      this.selectedIndex = null;
      this.shuffleAnswers();
    }
  }
```

When ESLint Runs its shows an error:
 `error  'immediate:' is defined but never used  no-unused-labels`

I have tried to modify the Pkg JSON as well with no luck

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  }
```

What's the correct config I need to change in ESLINT?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `immediate: true;` is invalid syntax as you have it in the `currentQuestion` handler function. ESLint is correct and does not need changes to its config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a watcher does not work as such: you are using a label instead of assigning a watcher config:

```
watch: {
  currentQuestion() {
    immediate: true;  // <--- Error here, this is a label, not a config key-value pair
    this.selectedIndex = null;
    this.shuffleAnswers();
  }
}
```

Because `immediate: true` is a key-value pair in an object, and shouldn't be found in a function. What you want is to convert `currentQuestion` into an object—refer to the documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch.

If additional settings is required for your watcher, you need to change it to an object and use `handler` to define the watcher function, and you can add additional config options to it as such:

```
watch: {
  currentQuestion: {
    handler: function () {
      this.selectedIndex = null;
      this.shuffleAnswers();
    },
    immediate: true
  },
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, `immediate: true` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) followed by a redundant Boolean expression. That's why the error is _"no-unused-labels"_

Comment: @Phil Even if you use the ignore next line comment, it will not work because VueJS will not recogize it as a watcher setting. In other words, silencing the es-lint error will not fix it: the watcher declaration itself needs to be changed. I've clarified my answer because it is technically not a syntax error tho ;)

Comment: Sorry, I was just picking up on your _"Because `immediate: true` is a key-value pair in an object"_. This is of course, the right answer